# C# Unity camera moving up and down speed is very slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The project uses the main camera with orthographic mode and rotation of 45 and 30 degrees in X and Y. How can I change the code so that the camera moves at the same speed up/down and left/right? In the current version, due to changing only two coordinates, I cannot get the same speed (the camera moves up and down very slowly). The Y coordinate does not change because this is the height and because of it it is not possible to correctly limit the camera.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    isDragged = true;
    touchStart = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}
else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    isDragged = false;
}
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && isDragged == true)
{
    Vector3 direction = touchStart - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    direction.y = 0;

    Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.transform.position + direction;
    newPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.x, -45, 45);
    newPosition.z = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.z, -45, 45);

    Camera.main.transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

I tried to add camera acceleration up and down, but it did not work. The speed is still different.

Comment: `direction.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the Y coordinate to X and Z:

```
    direction.x += direction.y;
    direction.z += direction.y;
    direction.y = 0;
```